# difference between CRoute and Jroute in Joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla, jomsocial, http-status-code-303

what difference between CRoute and Jroute in Joomla 3.

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
```

I have `$mainframe->redirect(CRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&view=register&task=registerProfileType', false));`
this redirect, and it dosent work , with 303 See other Error, but when I change my code to `$mainframe->redirect(JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&view=register&task=registerProfileType', false));`

Comment: `CRoute` is Community Builder's own class which I believe they used to extend Joomla's `JRoute`

Comment: Yes I know it, only I want now why it generate 303 error

Comment: Why do you have it tagged jomsocial?

Comment: That class used in Jomsocial

Answer (score 0):

From the JoomSocial Wiki:

> By using our own library, CRoute, which is a replacement for JRoute,
>   the link to any part of JomSocial will have the correct Itemid and
>   will help avoid any duplicate links.

Are you using that redirect link where? Are you sure the JomSocial libraries are loaded there?

From the example, you should include the library:

```
include_once JPATH_ROOT.'/components/com_community/libraries/core.php';
```

Then use the object:

```
// Get CUser object
$link = CRoute::_('index.php?option=com_community&view=profile&userid='.$userid);
echo '<a href="/.$link." mce_href="http://www.jomsocial.com/.$link.">View user profile</a>';
```